# Angular ng-repeat handlebars and <br /> tag

Tags: angularjs

What is the proper way of doing this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in controller.model">
    <td>{{i.var1}}<br />{{i.var2}}<br />{{i.var3}}</td>
</tr>
```

When this renders, the `<br/>` is displayed as plain text.

Do I really have to define variables for each line that has a `<br/>` in it and use the $sce to set it as trusted? That seems awfully silly.

If you find the same question, please let me know what search phrase you used.

#### Edit

When the page is rendered in dev tools, the html looks like this:

```
<td><p class="ng-binding">Approved.&lt;br&gt;.&lt;br&gt;<br><br></p></td>
```

It is written like this in the page:

```
<td><p>{{i.ProgramInitiation}}<br>{{i.RejectReasonInitiation}}<br>{{i.RejectReasonOtherInitiation}}</p></td>
```

Strange.  I'll play around with it as it obviously works in plunkr.

Comment: At a guess, I'd say your `ProgramInitiation` property has some HTML in it, specifically `"Approved.<br>.<br>"`

Comment: @Phil OMG. You're totally right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me. I tried this on a plunker.

```
<table>
      <tr ng-repeat="i in obj">
      <td>{{i.name}}<br/>{{i.lastname}}<br/>{{i.lastname}}</td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Check it out here: http://plnkr.co/edit/BrfLvssZ7IZZzIj2JqRo

Comment: I'll be darned, doesn't work that way in my code. Using angular 1.3.14. Maybe I have a small oversight somewhere. I'll dig around a bit.